# Jquery: How can I rewrite this code to be more efficient or conservative?

Tags: jquery, dry

The only difference in this code is the #position1,2,3.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    console.log(object);
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    console.log(object);
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

I want to write it where the function looks something similar like this.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', '#position2', '#position3' function(){
    console.log(object);
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Is there a way to do that? Because at the moment it does not work when I try it. I am not very good with jquery. Whats the best way to make this code more efficient?

Comment: No, I had to use the .one because I am updating multiple elements in my DOM. I have to immediately remove the listener after its been pressed.

Comment: The way to combine selectors is with comma in a single selector string: `'#position1, #position2, #position3'`

Comment: I really don't like seeing unnecessary repetition of codes. Is there a way for you to modify the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the `positionN` elements are siblings, you can use `.index()` to get their positions, then use that as the array index.

Instead of using IDs, give them all `class="position"`. Then do:

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '.position', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[$(this).index()]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Why do you think so? Did you read his first comment above about why he's using `.one()` intead of `.on()`?

Comment: Sorry no I didn't - I'm currently busy writing my own answer. lol. Nevermind then.